# Pandas: counter increasing each time conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some conditions and a Counter that Counts when condition A is met.

```
 date                      condition        count   
    01,01,2018 08:00             A               1
    01,01,2018 08:01             A               2
    01,01,2018 08:03             A               3
    01,01,2018 08:04             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:07             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:10             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:13             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:22             A               1
    01,01,2018 08:24             A               2
    01,01,2018 08:25             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:27             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:29             B               0
    01,01,2018 08:30             A               1
```

I would like that the Count doesn't reset each time condition changes.

```
date                      condition        count   
01,01,2018 08:00             A               1
01,01,2018 08:01             A               2
01,01,2018 08:03             A               3
01,01,2018 08:04             B               3
01,01,2018 08:07             B               3
01,01,2018 08:10             B               3
01,01,2018 08:13             B               3
01,01,2018 08:22             A               4
01,01,2018 08:24             A               5
01,01,2018 08:25             B               5
01,01,2018 08:27             B               5
01,01,2018 08:29             B               5
01,01,2018 08:30             A               6
```

At the Moment the code for the Count Looks like:

```
df['count']= df.groupby((df['condition'] = 'A').cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not

```
df['count']=df['condition'].eq('A').cumsum()
```

Comment: what if I have 2 conditions but I want to restart the Count each time are both met?? at the Moment I am trying ``df['count']= df.groupby(((df.condition1<50)&(df.condition2 < 10)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1  `` but it doesn't work, it simply start counting from the beginning to the end ignoring the conditions...can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I think [groupby.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) is what you're looking for

```
df['count']= df.groupby((df['Date']['condition']).cumsum())
```

and then later subset the df based on required condition.