# how to make this changing dataframe faster?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

```
list_nn = [k for k in list(df['job_keyword'].unique()) if not str(k).isdigit()]
i = 0
for  k in list_nn:
    df.loc[df.job_keyword == k ,'job_keyword'] = i
    df.loc[df.user_keyword == k , 'user_keyword'] = i
    i+=1
```

it's a loop through the data frame column and if its match with it change with number 
it takes more than 3 minutes is there a way to make this faster?

it's look though the entire dataframe I want to make it faster

Comment: Can you share at least some of your program and data? How are we supposed to improve the performance of a program we don’t understand and cannot run? In general, explicit loops should be a last resort when working with Pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: counter increasing each time conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379461/pandas-counter-increasing-each-time-conditions-are-met)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
df[df.job_keyword.isin(list_nn)] = df[df.job_keyword.isin(list_nn)].index
df[df.user_keyword.isin(list_nn)] = df[df.job_keyword.isin(list_nn)].index
```

Comment: You have no guarantee that the index is just a range of integer values.